# Python with Visual and VPython for graphics

Tags: python, matplotlib, vpython

Let me try and explain my problem better. I'm having problems with the VPython module and visual. If I run a python 2.7 script and use the "import visual" statement to let me make a plot, I get the following error message:

"This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are
logged in on the main display of your Mac."

If I run python scripts that use matplotlib to plot, everything works fine.
Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: I asked a similar question over a month ago and never received an answer. Please let me know if you find a solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install Python 2.7 from python.org before installing VPython? It sort of sounds like maybe VPython is trying to use the Python that comes already installed on the Mac.

I'll advertise that a better place to pose VPython questions is in the VPython forum at

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users